# Implementing passingTest that returns all nodes in the node’s subtree that satisfy a test

Tags: ios, swift, boolean, scenekit, arkit

I am not really sure how to really use this function. I searched the internet thoroughly but could not find an instance of an example of this function being used. In SceneKit, I am pretty familiar with the function that searches by the node's name.. but this one is confusing since it returns a reference to a bool, that specifies an array.. The definition goes like this

```
func childNodes(passingTest predicate: (SCNNode, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Bool) -> [SCNNode]
```

I got up to this point.. which gives me ALL the nodes I do not know why..

```
let ballToDisappear = sceneView?.scene.rootNode.childNodes(passingTest: { (node, ballYesOrNo) -> Bool in
        if (node.position.x < (maxVector?.x)! && node.position.x > (minVector?.x)!){
            if (node.position.y < (maxVector?.y)! && node.position.y > (minVector?.y)!){
                if (node.position.z < (maxVector?.z)! && node.position.z > (minVector?.z)!){
                    return ballYesOrNo.pointee.boolValue
                }
            }
        }
                    return !ballYesOrNo.pointee.boolValue
    }
    )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The definition of [`childNodes(passingTest:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407982-childnodes) expects a closure that takes two arguments and returns a Bool. The arguments to the closure are:

- `child` => the node to check (called `node` by you)
- `stop` => indicates to stop the test. Calling this `ballYesOrNo` as you did is inherently confusing, better name it `stop` as the documentation suggests.

So you'd have to *modify*  `stop` if and only if you want to stop the algorithm. You'd never want to *return* the value of `stop` *directly*.

To say that a child node matches, you have to return `true`, else `false`.
Therefore:

```
let ballToDisappear = sceneView?.scene.rootNode.childNodes(passingTest: { (node, stop) -> Bool in
    if (node.position.x < (maxVector?.x)! && node.position.x > (minVector?.x)!){
        if (node.position.y < (maxVector?.y)! && node.position.y > (minVector?.y)!){
            if (node.position.z < (maxVector?.z)! && node.position.z > (minVector?.z)!){
                return false // or false here and true below??
            }
        }
    }
                return true // or true here, see above, depends on your logic
}
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is really helplful

Comment: @Haroon do you need more help? If this or another answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to accept that answer. Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [Why is voting important?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).